# How do i show product varient in react js with drop down menu without duplicate value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, database, mongodb

I am creating e-commerce app in node , mongoDb and react. i have two model one for product and another for product varient. i want to show the product varient data in react like size in drop down  and color as radio button. But I am getting duplicate value of color and size . like small size 2 times  or color pink 2  or 3 times while showing its varient. I am requesting the for two request one for product and another for its varient.

Here is varient model

```
// Here is my backend code for creating product varient

ProductVarient_Model.create({
    stock: Data.stock,
    price: Data.price,
    product: Data.productid,
    assets: {
        images: [image url]
    },
    product_attribute: Data.attributes,
    seller: req.user_id
})

// Data.attributes is look like this
[{ "color": "pink", "size": "medium" }]


// here is my product code for endpoint /v4/api/product/id
const { id } = req.params;
    await ProductModel.findById(id)
        .exec((error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 400))
            }
            else {
                if (data === null) {
                    next(new ErrorHandler("No product found", 400))
                }
                else {
                    return res.status(200).json({ data })
                    // return res.status(200).json({ data: data })
                }

            }
        })
```

if a product varients with size medium is available in 3 color so size medium is three time repeat in varients what i don't want.

In this data product_attribute  color value slilver is 3 times in whole data .But logically we can only show color silver only one time. same goes with the size with different color .

if a product is availble in 3 sizes and 3 colors total vaient of a product is 9 and its value show 3 times. i want to show only one.

Here is my frontend code

```
useEffect(() => {
        const result = Promise.all([
            fetch(`http://localhost:5000/v4/api/product/${id}`, {
                method: "GET",
                credentials: 'include'
            }).then(async (res) => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    const { data } = await res.json();
                    setProduct_detail([data])
                }
            })
                .catch(error => console.log(error)),
            fetch(`http://localhost:5000/v3/api/product/varientById/${id}`, {
                method: "GET",
                credentials: 'include'
            })
                .then(async (res) => {
                    if (res.status === 200) {
                        const { data } = await res.json();
                        setProduct_varient(data)
                    }
                })
        ])
    }, [])

    const Attributes = () => {
        const ProductAttribute = [];
        product_varient.forEach(element => {
            const { product_attribute } = element;
            product_attribute.map(item => {
                ProductAttribute.push(item)
            })

        });
        return ProductAttribute;
    }
    const Atr = Attributes();

{
    product_details.map((item)=>(
        // some code 
        {
            Atr.map((element, index) => (
             <option value={element.size}
                  className='size_option hover:bg-indigo-700 hover:text-white'>
                    {element.size}
             </option>
            ))
                    
    ))
}
```

Varient data look like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      
      "product_attribute": [
        {
          "color": "silver",
          "size": "small"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      
      "product_attribute": [
        {
          "color": "silver",
          "size": "medium"
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      
      "product_attribute": [
        {
          "color": "silver",
          "size": "large"
        }
      ],
     
    },
    {
      "product_attribute": [
        {
          "color": "pink",
          "size": "large"
        }
      ]
    
    },
    {
      "product_attribute": [
        {
          "color": "pink",
          "size": "small"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      
      "product_attribute": [
        {
          "color": "pink",
          "size": "medium"
        }
      ],
    
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `/api/product/:id` end-point code?

Comment: I added the product code for fetching product data in backend.